# Не работает регулярка nginx

Tags: регулярные-выражения, nginx

Делал на днях редирект на html-снапшот страницы в случае, если в строке запроса есть `_escaped_fragment_=` и его значение чему-то равняется. Крутая поддержка Яндекса сказала мне, мол, да, всё будет хорошо, всё будет работать. Оказалось, что поддержка Яндекса сама не понимает, о чём пишет. Оказывается, Яндекс-бот тупо доставляет в конце URL параметр `_escaped_fragment_=` и оставляет его пустым.

Собственно, проблема в том, что до этого у меня была регулярка:

```
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=(.+)") {
    rewrite ^ /snapshots/$uri last;
}
```

И она работала для строк типа

> domain.ru/?_escaped_fragment_=tickets/moscow/simferopol/

Теперь же, мне нужно переписать регулярку так, чтобы она определяла такую строку

> domain.ru/tickets/moscow/simferopol/?_escaped_fragment_=

Перебробовал разные регулярки:

```
$args ~* "_escaped_fragment_="
$args ~ "_escaped_fragment_="
$args ~ "(.+)_escaped_fragment_="
```

Ничего из этого не работает. Какая мне нужна регулярка?

**UPD:**

В сервисах для проверки регулярных выражений для строки `/tickets/moscow/simferopol/?_escaped_fragment_=` подходит регулярное выражение:

> $request_uri ~ "(.+)?_escaped_fragment="

Но при использовании такой регулярки ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снимаю. Проблема заключалась не в регулярном выражении, а в том, что nginx находил более подходящий `location` в котором не было условия на проверку `$args`. В итоге заработала регулярка:

> $args ~ "_escaped_fragment_"